# How to store ArrayList with custom objects in to cache using LRU disk cache

Tags: java, android, caching, arraylist

I am working on a project where i need to store and retrieve the arraylist with custom objects into cache memory of android.  I tried [this](https://github.com/anupcowkur/Reservoir) library but i couldnt able to achieve my task since that library is only for storing objects. I also wants to know is there any other method to store arraylist in cache memory.  
My Custom object class is

```
class TestClass {
    private String testString;
    private String name;
    private String age;

    public String getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }

    public void setTestString(String testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
```

My mainactivity where i pass the arraylist is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<TestClass> test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       test = new ArrayList<TestClass>;

    }
```

Please kindly help me to proceed further by sharing some piece of code.

Comment: maybe you need to implement Serializable on TestClass class?

Comment: aren't classic java.io classes available on Android? You should be able to easly serialize a using an OutputStream, see http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57